# R: categorize all numeric variables (1:0) according to a cut-off

Tags: r, categorization

I have the following data frame:

```
structure(list(test1 = c(0.12, 0.2, 0.55, 0.22, 0.19, 0.17, 0.15, 
0.12, 0.32, 0.23, 0.32, 0.23), test2 = c(0.15, 0.12, 0.32, 0.23, 
0.12, 0.2, 0.55, 0.22, 0.12, 0.2, 0.55, 0.22), test3 = c(0.07, 
0.01, 0, 0.13, 0.16, 0.78, 0.98, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5), test4 = c(0.23, 
0.12, 0.2, 0.2, 0.55, 0.22, 0.12, 0.2, 0.55, 0.22, 0.55, 0.42
)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

And I am trying to write a script which, for each variables (test1, test2, test3...), creates (and add to the data frame) a dicotomic variable (named as out_testX) depending if the variable value is major or equal to .20.

The results, should be something like this:

```
structure(list(test1 = c(0.12, 0.2, 0.55, 0.22, 0.19, 0.17, 0.15, 
0.12, 0.32, 0.23, 0.32, 0.23), test2 = c(0.15, 0.12, 0.32, 0.23, 
0.12, 0.2, 0.55, 0.22, 0.12, 0.2, 0.55, 0.22), test3 = c(0.07, 
0.01, 0, 0.13, 0.16, 0.78, 0.98, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5), test4 = c(0.23, 
0.12, 0.2, 0.2, 0.55, 0.22, 0.12, 0.2, 0.55, 0.22, 0.55, 0.42
), out_test1 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), out_test2 = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), out_test3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), out_test4 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `mutate_all`, we pass the function in the `list` specify a suffix to be added to column name, and if it needs to be prefix, do this in `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
     mutate_all( list(out = ~+( . >= .2))) %>%
     rename_at(vars(ends_with('out')), ~ str_replace(., '(.*)_(out)', '\\2_\\1'))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1[paste0("out_", names(df1))] <- +(df1 >= .2)
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun! Is there a way to categorize on the base of the absolute value of the variables? E.g. even -0.25 to be categorized as 1?

Comment: @MarianoCGiglio. IN that case just do `+(abs(df1) >= .2)` and in `dplyr`, wrap `+(abs(.) >= .2)`